# Does the asp.net RoleManager really cache the roles for a user in a cookie if so configured?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, roleprovider

In my web.config I have the Role Manager configured as follows:

```
<roleManager enabled="true" cacheRolesInCookie="true" cookieName=".ASPROLES" 
cookieTimeout="30" cookiePath="/" cookieRequireSSL="false" 
cookieSlidingExpiration="true" cookieProtection="All">
```

however in our custom RoleProvider it would seems that the GetRolesForUser method is always being called, rather than as I would have expected, the RoleManager serving up the roles from its cookie.

We're using something like to get the roles for a user:

```
string[] myroles = Role.GetRolesForUser("myuser");
```

Is there something that I'm missing in the configuration, or in the use of the RoleManager

Comment: There's a typo in your code sample - cacheRolesInCookie="ture".

Comment: A straight copy & paste of your config works for me, except I also specify a default provider.

Comment: Maybe this link describe the same problem you are experience? http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/104688/rolemanager-cacherolesincookie-option-does-not-work I also have this problem, and i can´t get my custom rolemanager to store the roles into a cookie.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are missing `defaultProvider="yourRoleProviderName"` in your web.config .

Do you call the method below for any user or for current user only? Cookie caching works only for current user roles.

```
Role.GetRolesForUser("myuser");
```

Check that .ASPROLES cookie is sent to browser after the fist call of `IsInRole` or `GetRoles` method.

Answer (score 1):

It might work better if you were to change the value in your `cacheRolesInCookie` to `true`.

Comment: the typo was not in the code, but introduced when I retyped the code.